# Use a common container registry in k8s deployments in a federated cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, harbor

**Setup**

- I have a federated k8s cluster that each cluster has master and workers.
- In a federation, each cluster has a different domain for accessing image registry. (e.g. myregistry-1, myregistry-2).
- In other words, each cluster has its own registry.

*Question*

- I don't want to change domain for each cluster. Basically, I would like to create a common endpoint that matches to each inner registry, which is internal to that cluster.

Example: Below deployment on all clusters.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: harbor.default:5000/nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

I tried to implement "[Services without selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)" and created an endpoint and updated deployment.yaml but didn't work.

**harbor.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: harbor-service
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

**harbor-endpoint.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: harbor-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: <INTERNAL_IP_OF_REGISTRY>
    ports:
      - port: 5000
```

Comment: Hello @efdestegul Which solution are you using to implement a federated k8s cluster? Because as I can see, you use basic deployment for harbor in your example.

Comment: Well problem is not about fedaration. It is related with kubelet. How can I force kubelet to use a domain name that it is not aware of? (Because k8s service is only in the context of cluster not on the node itself.)

Comment: Sorry for delay. Have you solved this problem?

Comment: Nope this doesn’t seem feasible.. because contexts are different..

Comment: Regarding your `harbor-service` Service. Is it working? What about `nginx-deployment` deployment? If it fails, what is a reason?